# Heroku Django: Reconnecting and Updating

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I've finished the Heroku tutorial on how to upload and launch a basic django based web app using the following:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#gitignore

Can anybody provide steps or a link to documentation on how to re-connect to Heroku and properly upload changes you've made to your site?  Starting from a fresh terminal and cd'ing into the folder where your manage.py and procfiles live, what would the following steps be?

I then do:

$ virtualenv venv --distribute

$ source venv/bin/activate

after this i try to run $python manage.py runserver but it can't find django  modules etc...

Do I need to reinstall django everytime I go to git push an update on the server?

Comment: did you push to heroku? `git push heroku master`

Comment: yea, i just tried that again but it returns:  "Everythign up-to-date".

Perhaps the better question to ask is from a fresh terminal window, what steps do you take to reinitiate your virtual environment, connect to heroku, select a specific app and then update that app.  These are all steps I'm unclear with being new to both virtual envs and heroku.

Comment: @user2113934 - why don't you edit your question to reflect the fact that you'd like to know how o re-initiate your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

1. Heroku is just git, basically. At least on your computer.
2. So you don't need to "connect" to Heroku. You just `cd` to your source folder and use it as you would a normal git repository.
3. If you're using a virtualenv (which you should be), after you cd to your directory, you'll need to reactivate the virtualenv. If you followed heroku's Django tutorial, it'll probably be the command `source venv/bin/activate`
4. If you want to dig into some of herokus commands, [download the Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com).
5. To test whether your Procfile is working, use [Honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho). It's a python version of `foreman`, Heroku's Ruby-based local Procfile runner.

Answer (score 0):

To see which files are on your Heroku app:

Launch the bash on heroku by typing this command on your terminal:

```
heroku run bash --app appname
```

From there just ls and see your folders.